# How to hide a Facebook post from timeline?

Tags: facebook, hide, facebook-timeline

I'm desperate to hide a Facebook post (mine or a friend's post) on my own Timeline but it doesn't work, I don't even know if it is possible !

What I've done is :

1. First, I checked on my timeline on the specific post if it can be hidden or not
2. I implemented this code :

   ```
   facebookClient.publish(String.format("%s", postKey), Post.class, Parameter.with("is_hidden", "true"));
   ```

I have actually a response like :

```
 missing parameter reorder_pids[]
```

If I specify it, it asks me for a valid merge photo id etc. But I'm not sure if I am in the wrong direction. One of my colleague told me that it works for him but impossible to determine what is the difference.

I tried this function on a normal account and also a Facebook page.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
String _mode = "hidden";    // or "normal" or "starred"
facebookClient.publish(_post, FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("timeline_visibility", _mode));
```

As soon as Post will be hidden - you won't be able to retrieve it by FQL request, even by post_id. It is almost like "delete". But you can still publish with timeline_visibility=normal.